# Running fork, dup2 and exec from a C program in background

Tags: c, linux, bash

I'm developing a embedded C application (`gather.out`) for a controller that runs Debian 8 (Jessie). This application calls another program called gather. The gather program prints some data on screen when I run it alone on the terminal. I decided to use `fork` and `dup2` to redirect the output to a output file that contains the gathered data, as follows:

```C
pid_t pid=fork();

/* Child process */
if(pid==0)
{
    // Open gather output file
    int gather_file_fd=open(actual_filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0777);
    if(gather_file_fd==-1)
    {
        return 2;
    }

    // Make stdout of gather program as input of output gather file
    int gather_file_fd_dup=dup2(gather_file_fd, STDOUT_FILENO);

    // Run the gather program
    int err;
    err=execl("/usr/bin/gather","gather","-w",NULL);
    if(err==-1)
    {
        return 2;
    }

}
```

Everything goes fine when I run it from the terminal, manually. When I set the controller to run it as startup (I don't know exactly how the controller start the program on boot, but it does) my output file gets corrupted.

I don't know how to debug this problem but I was trying to see the TTY of the processes to have some idea about what's happening using `ps ux | grep gather`. When running manually:

```bash
# ps ux | grep gather
root     18014 49.4  0.3 219380  6240 pts/0    RLl+ 14:50   0:51 ./gather.out
root     18022 39.2  0.2 219304  5988 pts/0    RLl+ 14:52   0:01 gather -w
root     18026  0.0  0.0   2076   568 pts/22   S+   14:52   0:00 grep gather
```

And running at startup:

```shell
# ps ux | grep gather
root     17859 80.5  0.3 219380  6240 ?        RLl  14:42   0:33 /var/ftp/usrflash/Project/C Language/Background Programs/gather.out
root     17978 45.0  0.2 219304  5984 ?        RLl  14:43   0:01 gather -w
root     17982  0.0  0.0   2076   532 pts/0    S+   14:43   0:00 grep gather
```

From there I noticed that there is no TTY attached to the processes running the program at startup. Does it affect the way I redirect the output with `fork`, `dup2` and `execl`?

**Edit 1**

The correct output file must be like this (produced by gather application, runing `gather -w > /var/ftp/gather/test.txt` on the terminal and start the data acquisition on controller's IDE):

```
Waiting to gather
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
...
```

Where each line `0 0 0` is the sampled signals from the controller and could be any value, the `...` indicates that the file is very large. When I run the gather program on the terminal `gather -w > /var/ftp/gather/test.txt &`, start data acquisition on controller's IDE, the gather program suddenly stops when I hit enter on terminal:

```bash
# gather -w > /var/ftp/gather/test.txt &
[2] 22232

#

[2]+  Stopped                 gather -w > /var/ftp/gather/test.txt
#
```

And the output file prints just the header:

```
Waiting to gather
```

Starting the gather program in background using `gather -w < /dev/null >& /var/ftp/gather/test.txt &` as one of the comments' advices and starting the data acquisition on controller's IDE I got the following file output:

```
Waiting to gather
Waiting to gather
Waiting to gather
Waiting to gather
...
```

The number of lines on the file is much greater than the number of samples on sample counter watched by IDE. My guess lies on a bug in the `gather` program. Unfortunatly I don't have gather's source code because it's part of natively programs of the controller.

Comment: How are you opening the fd to the output file. My suspicion is, that the issue is not with the redirect itself, but the way you're opening the destination file.

Comment: If `execl()` succeeds, it doesn't return; if it returns, it failed.  There is no need to test the return value.  The mere fact that the code is after the `execl()` means your code should log an error and exit.

Comment: In theory, the code run from startup should not be affected by not having a terminal.  Another probable difference is the current working directory, which is likely the root directory.  The program is running as root too; I trust it is careful with what it writes where.

Comment: @datenwolf thanks for replying me. I'm sorry, I just forget to include the `open` line when I was cleaning the code to post here. I edited the question including `int gather_file_fd=open(actual_filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0777);`

Comment: I would recommend much more restrictive permissions than 0777 on the file.  You aren't creating an executable, and you don't want the hoi polloi modifying it. Use 0644 or 0644 permission.  Consider whether the general public should be able to read it.  If not, use 0640.  You could even use 0400 so only the owner can read the file; the process that creates the file can still write to it until the file descriptor is closed.

Comment: How are you logging errors? Simply returning is not sufficient.  You need to write log messages to a log file, or perhaps to the `syslog` daemon via the `syslog()` family of functions.  Give all the available information — file name and error number and so on.

Comment: Hi @JonathanLeffler, thanks for replying me. As it is the first time I'm doing this kind of implementation I'm wrote it this way but after some search and study I realized that I could just print some error message that it would be redirected automatically to the output file. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the root directory of this controller is read only and I can't write to `/` without doing `mount -o remount,rw /`. There are some specific folders, as I set on the `actual_filename` variable as `/var/ftp/gather/` that have write permission natively.

Comment: Don't forget to include PID and date/time and so on in the messages, especially if the file might be used by multiple processes.  The log file should be opened with `O_APPEND`. And you should check its size and switch log files periodically.  Eventually, you will need to do log file management.  It isn't an immediate priority.  But writing log information carefully will.make it easier to debug.  Make sure both programs are in agreement about where to read from and write to.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm going to restrict the file permissions but we have to keep in mind that this controller has only root user. This file will be transfered to a NFS after successfully acquired. I just let it 0777 because it was an example that I found to start the program.

Comment: Yeah; many examples written without consideration of the Internet use sloppy permissions.  There never was a good reason for execute permission.  Very few programs write executable code.  But 0666 was recommended even though anyone could modify the file.  The argument is that the `umask` setting would limit the damage, but that is subverted by setting the `umask` to zero.  These days, programs should be cautious, at least about who can write to it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm going to set up the `syslog` to get more information about what's happening with my code. I was just using `printf` and I already know that this isn't the best way of doing that, I just thought that the problem wasn't so deep as it is. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: not sure if the command also requires stdin and stderr. do you have to handle the redirection by yourself? could you just use `system("/usr/bin/gather < /dev/null >& /the/log/file")`? or `execl("/bin/bash", "bash", "-c", "/usr/bin/gather -w < /dev/null >& /the/log/file", NULL)`?

Comment: @pynexj I tryed to use `system` in earlier implementations but it does not return me the process PID and it lock the code on the call, which is undesired on my application. I'm going to test the second advice but now I'm suspecting about the controller's native `gather` program, I ran it directly on the terminal in background `gather -w > /var/ftp/gather/test.txt &` and none has been printed to file. Maybe it's a `gather` limitation itself.

Comment: `gather -w > /var/ftp/gather/test.txt &` -- try `gather -w < /dev/null >& /var/ftp/gather/test.txt &`

Comment: @pynexj I edited my question including some tests that I did with `gather`. I don't know if it is possible to debug those problems without source code, maybe using `gdb` or something like that.

Comment: i suspect the `gather` program requires a tty to run properly. you can try tools like [tag:expect], [tag:pexpect] or [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect).